# The boundary of a set in relation to the interior and closure of the set

Tags: general-topology

How do we go about proving that $\partial A = \overline{A}\setminus A^{o}$ where $A^{o}$ is the interior of set A?

To go about proving this I know we need $A^{o} = X \setminus\overline{X\setminus A}$

He said to prove it using De Morgan's Laws? How do I prove this?

Just to clarify some things, that might help people inform me:

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A \subset X$. The closure $\overline{A}$ of $A$ is defined as $\overline{A} = \cap_{C closed, A \subset C} C$.

The boundary of A is $\partial A :=$ {${x \in X: \forall \epsilon > 0, B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap A \neq \emptyset \neq B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap (X \setminus A)}$}

Useful properties:

- $\overline{A} =$ {${x \in X: \forall \epsilon > 0, B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap A \neq \emptyset}$} = {${x \in X: \forall N \in N_x, N \cap A \neq \emptyset}$}
- $\partial A = \overline{A} \cap \overline{X \setminus A}$
- $\partial A = \partial (X \setminus A)$

Comment: how do you define $\partial A$?

Comment: @QED the boundary of set A

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I edited it

Comment: No that much I understood, I was asking how do you define boundary of a set?

Comment: @QED Let (X,d) be a metric space and A $\subset$ X, then $\partial$A := {x $\in$ X: $\forall \epsilon > 0, B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap A \neq \emptyset \neq B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap (X\A)$}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $x \in \partial A$. Then for every $\epsilon > 0$, $B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap A \ne \emptyset$, i.e. there exists $a_{\epsilon} \in A$ such that $a_{\epsilon} \in B_{\epsilon}(x)$. Since this is true for any arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$, we must have that $x$ is a limit point of $A$, and hence $x \in \overline{A}$. If $x \in A^\circ$, then $\exists \epsilon>0$ such that $B_{\epsilon}(x) \subseteq A$, but that implies $B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap (X \setminus A) = \emptyset$, which contradicts the definition of $\partial A$. Hence we must have $x \not\in A^\circ$. Thus $x \in \overline{A} \setminus A^\circ$. Hence $\partial A \subseteq \overline{A} \setminus A^\circ$.

The reverse inclusion, i.e., $\overline{A} \setminus A^\circ \subseteq\partial A$, also follows from similar, even simpler arguments.